# DOM element behind previous one

Tags: html, css, sass

I don't understand why my `<div class="text">{{ diff }}</div>` is not visible. It's behind my component and `z-index` doesn't help.

```
<div class="chart">
  <div class="spent" :style="{ flex: flexSpent }"></div>
  <div class="remaining" :style="{ flex: flexRemaining }"></div>
</div>
<div class="text">{{ diff }}</div>
```

The div `.text` is behind the div `.chart`, what am I doing wrong?

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Dooxe/pen/awGjoz)

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask] - all relevant code belongs directly into your question.

Comment: And secondly, and this is CSS 101: z-index only works on positioned elements. So add `position:relative`, and z-index will work fine.

Comment: The codepen is very different from the code you have provided in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use `z-index`, you must set `position` to `absolute` or `relative`.

CSS for your `.text` should be as follow:

```
.text {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100%;
        position:relative;
}
```